# Does an airplane need a key to start?

Tags: engine, security

Does an airplane require a key to unlock the doors and start the aircraft engines?

Is it somewhat like how a car does?

Answer (score 2):

My 1973 Cessna Cardinal has a key to unlock the doors and another to start the engine.  Just like a car.

I could use a horn to scare deer & geese off the runway.

Comment: >I could use a horn to scare deer & geese off the runway :)

Comment: Same for '66 Piper Cherokee, and all the other non-glider airplanes I've flown.  And it's not really the deer on the runway when I want to take off that bother me, it's the ones that lurk on the side until you're halfway down, then bolt across :-)

Comment: 8-point buck got hit by a low wing Piper at my airport late Sunday doing that. Dented the wing lower leading edge, tore the Pitot rube from its mount.  Killed the deer.

Comment: On further thought, it's not "just like" a car.  In a car (at least before the newer push a button ones), you turn the key to start.  In the Cherokee and IIRC other planes, the key controls the magnetos, so it has 4 positions: off, left, right, and both.  To start, you turn the key to "both", and press a button to engage the starter.  Then when you do your runup, you switch to "left" and "right", and check for an RPM drop (and that the engine keeps running!).

Comment: In older Cessnas (early 70s, what I am familiar with), it is like a car. Turn full clockwise to spin the engine & engage the magnetos, release to both, then counterclockwise one position to one mag, two positions for the other mag.  There is no separate start button.

Comment: @CrossRoads: Yes, but there's still the 3 positions for the magnetos (and no ACC position :-)), so not "just like" a car.

Comment: But it's like a car in a lot of ways.